# Adicionar caracteres antes de cada numero

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma string em um textarea que ficará nesse formato:

```
2199998888
2188889999
2455556666
2566665555
```

Ou seja, números de telefone com quebra de linha para separá-los dentro do textarea.

A minha necessidade é inserir o código do pais em todos os números de telefone.

Não consegui achar uma lógica simples para fazer isso.

O resultado seria esse:

```
552199998888
552188889999
552455556666
552566665555
```

Comment: Não entendo muito de padrões de número de telefone, mas se é o código de um país não é necessário usar `+`? (`+552199998888`, etc)

Comment: Nesse caso em específico não preciso do + @mgibsonbr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta quebrar o conteúdo em linhas e adicionar `'55'` no início de cada uma. Assim, por exemplo:

```js
var campo = document.querySelector('textarea');
var linhas = campo.value.split("\n");
var novo = linhas.map(function(item) {
  return item ? '55' + item : item; // se a linha estiver em branco, não acrescenta '55'
}).join('\n');
campo.value = novo;
```

```html
<textarea rows="5">
2199998888
2188889999

2455556666
2566665555
</textarea>
```

Comment: bfavaretto, adicionei um if ali pra não mostrar o 55 solto no final.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Alterei novamente contando com linhas em branco já que é uma situação bastante provável.